# Rails: I have devise confirmable installed but I want a seperate mailer for contact me and other features

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer, devise-confirmable

**Rails 3**

I currently have Devise confirmable installed and everything works great. My question is, How can I have a seperate mailer for other parts of the app?

What I would like to have happen:
I want to have a contact me form or I want to have other forms that user fills out that get emailed to admin for review.

Can devise also handle this? Or do I need to run a seperate mailer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have separate mailer, and it is better to have separate mailer instead of making devise handle all mail.

ActionMailer basics: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: Thanks! I guess I am worried about changing UsersController Create Method...since devise takes care of all that. Am I going to run into problems when creating my own action mailer while Devise already has its action mailer set up?

Comment: You can have any amount of mailers set up, no limitations.

Comment: Really? Ok interesting thanks. I will give it a shit and report back.